# Ajax call Parm String, return JSON List

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to pass a string in an AJAX call POST to retrieve a List in JSON.

Here is my code that triggers the call:

```
<script>

    var a = {};

    a.theatreList = <%= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TheatreList) %> ; 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
          //  if (a.theatreList != null){                
                //ko.applyBindings(new theatreSel.TheatreModel(a.theatreList));
                ko.applyBindings(new theatreSel.TheatreModel(a.theatreList));
                Regal.showLocationModal();
                return false;

          //  }
        });
      });

</script>
```

Here is the .js that contains the .AJAX call

(

```
function (window) {

    var $ = window.jQuery;
        console = window.console,       
        Regal = window.Regal;
        theatreData = window.theatreData;

        function getEm(zip) {

                $.ajax('/Services/TheatreLocationList.asmx/getTheatres',
                       {
                           data: (zip),
                           type: 'POST',
                           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                           dataType: 'json'
                       }).done(function(){
                           alert("you did it!");
                       });                   

        }

    // declare viewmodel constructors in standard fashion
    function TheatreModel(tl) {
        var self = this;

        getEm("60613");
        self.theatreData = ko.observableArray(tl || []);         

    }



    var theatres = {};
    // declare the module exports     
    theatres.TheatreModel = TheatreModel;

    window.theatreSel = theatres;
```

and finally the .asmx

```
namespace Regal.Web.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for TheatreLocationList
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class TheatreLocationList : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public List<dynamic> getTheatres(String zip)
        {
            List<dynamic> TheatreList = new List<dynamic>();
            int radius = Regal.Core.Helpers.ConfigHelper.GetIntValue("SearchRadius", 30);
            IFrdiTheatreRepository frdiTheatreRepo = FrdiTheatreRepository.CreateBusinessObject();
            TheatreCollection theatreCollection = frdiTheatreRepo.GetAllTheatresFromRegalByPostalCode("60613", radius);
            TheatreList = theatreCollection.ToList<dynamic>();
            return TheatreList;


        } 
    }
}


    })(window)
```

I am getting an Internal Server error 500, but more importantly, I don't really know how to formulate the AJAX call, passing the parm, and returning the JSON LIST. I have been trying to find the syntax, but I am not seeing anything on what I am attempting to do.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/getTheatres'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/getTheatres'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/getTheatres'.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +713331
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +308
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +89
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +516
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: Have you added the HttpGet and HttpPost protocols to your web config? see http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/09/04/FIX-Request-format-is-unrecognized-for-URL-unexpectedly-ending-in.aspx

Comment: that isn't an issue, we have other programs using this. My issue is actually more narrowed down to getting my datatype to return correctly in JSON. Apparently, I have to return a list in JSON, but having issues with that part. thanks for your response